# Error #1010 in actionscript code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In code:

```
  override public function stateEventNewPlayer(param1:Player) : void
  {
     this.menu.chatView.log("* " + param1.name + " has joined");
     this.menu.refreshPlayers();
     Sounds.join.play();
     dispatchEvent(new InGameChatSendMessageEvent("test"));
  }
```

i have an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at gamecode.controllers::NetGameHost/onMessageReceived()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at basnet::BasNetPeer/onMessageReceived()
```

First three lines works correctly but when i added fourth line I get an error.
Error causes the line:

```
dispatchEvent(new InGameChatSendMessageEvent("test"));
```

Code:

```
override public function onMessageReceived(param1:MessageEvent) : void
  {
     var _loc3_:* = null as ByteArray;
     var _loc4_:uint = 0;
     var _loc5_:* = null as RemovePlayerAction;
     super.onMessageReceived(param1);
     try
     {
        _loc3_ = param1.data;
        _loc4_ = uint(_loc3_.readUnsignedByte());
        ...
        return;
     }
     break loop0;
  }
```

Please help.
Greetings.

Comment: The last block is a code, produced by decompiler. It seems that the author of the original code took certain measures and applied obfuscation/protection to it. Obfuscation/protection are exactly measures against decompilers. This code is not meant to be read/understood/compiled ever again. Please stop doing what you are doing. Stealing other people work is not a nice thing to do.

Comment: Look at [**this PDF**](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Oh-The-Art-of-Reverse-Engineering-Flash-Exploits-wp.pdf). Just read the section titled _"Decompilers"_ (pages 1 & 2) the important part is : _"...There is a lot of heavily **obfuscated** code out there that makes decompiling simply impossible or severely broken. Some decompilers **simply output the best code they can produce**, but never warn when the code **can possibly be broken**."_

Comment: PS: looks like me and @Organis just posted same advice at same time. Two AS3 coders now telling you that your code won't work if written like this. For example : Why `var _loc3_:* = null as ByteArray;`? You cannot null something in AS3 then later try to set a value such as `_loc3_ = param1.data;`. Also since `param1` is of **type** `MessageEvent` why try reading bytes from an Event? If you learn how real AS3 code works then you'd achieve same thing as posted function using 3 lines of code instead of the shown 8 lines. Finally If `= null as ByteArray;` didn't seem like a bad idea to you...

Answer (score 0):

Set "permit debugging" to true and in the stack trace you will also see the line number to which the error happens. This helps really a lot.